# Why am I unable to mount file shares between two ubuntu machines?

Tags: networking, samba, file-sharing

I have shared my Videos folder in the home directory of my netbook and am attempting to access it from the new laptop I just got. Samba is installed on both machines, as well as smbclient. File sharing is enabled and I can see the netbook in the "Network" entry of nautilus, but when I attempt to open the computer to access the shared folder I receive the error:

"Unable to mount location    DBus error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did no receive a reply (timeoutby message bus)"

A timeout error seems odd since it appears instantly. This occurs on both machines (e.g. I share a file on the laptop and attempt to open it from the netbook).

Comment: This isn't a direct response to your question, but have you considered using NFS instead of Samba? Samba is designed to allow Linux servers to masquerade as Microsoft servers; NFS is for sharing folders and filesystems between Linux and Unix machines in a LAN, and is simpler and more robust.

Comment: I just enabled sharing on the folders via the GUI in nautilus, beyond that my expertise with networking is a bit bare-bones. =)

I'm totally up for whatever will allow me to move 100gb across an ad-hoc network in less time than my awful 10MBit/Sec router will.

Comment: How is your network laid out? Is it a direct cable between the computers? (If so, could you post the output of `ifconfig` from each computer? There's a possibility that neither computer has a network address.)  I like to use SFTP between Linux computers (it seems more reliable than samba, and it's very secure, I.E. everything's encrypted).

Answer (score 3):

Connect each computer to the internet and install the 'ssh' package. Then plug the computers directly into each other.

On computer A, do this:
`sudo ip addr add 192.168.18.1/24 dev eth0`

On computer B, do this:
`sudo ip addr add 192.168.18.2/24 dev eth0`

Then you can mount the filesystem over sftp in nautilus and copy that way just like you would between drives. On the computer you want to run the copy from, open nautilus and Click Go -> Location...   In the address bar put `sftp://<username you want to access files as>@<other computer's ip address` . So, for example, if you are on computer A and computer B has the user 'james' you could do something like this: `sftp://james@192.168.18.2` and press enter. It should ask for your password for the james user on computer B and then it should show the files on computer B. Copy and Paste the files to where you want them.

Comment: SSH (and sftp) are a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

In nautilus click Go -> Location... fill the field,

```
smb://<ip-address>/ or smb://<ip-address>/<shared folder>/
```